# A question regarding Leonard Susskind's ER=EPR lecture

Tags: quantum-mechanics, general-relativity, spacetime, quantum-entanglement

https://youtu.be/OBPpRqxY8Uw?t=1315 Right at this instance of the video Susskind starts talking about how space is actually connected by entanglement. (You should watch the video for a accurate understanding of his statements.). This claim feels very superficial to me. Later on the lecture he also talks about the "monogamy" property of entanglement, that an object can be entangled to only a single object. But if this is the case how can space be held together by entanglement because for it to be the case a single region of space must be entangled to all the other neighbouring regions which defy the monogamy property.

So I have mainly 3 questions:

1. How can space be held together by entanglement?
2. Why is there property of entanglement such as monogamy?
3. If we accept that the monogamy property is correct how can space be held together by entanglement?

Comment: An alternative introduction  to this with less hype: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=WQU9yOtWrQk

Comment: @BruceGreetham Thank you for the lecture and do you have any sort of reading material for this topic?

Comment: This was the simplest essay I could find when I was looking into this https://arxiv.org/abs/1005.3035 :  to get you started.